# Fail to call API even though my logged-in email has read-permission to GAds

Tags: permissions, google-ads-api

My email has read-permissions to a Google-Ads account.

[image: https://screenshot.googleplex.com/9aDHbu6kX7KqY2H]

Nevertheless I fail to call gAds API via apps script and get this error:

"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"

[image]

The app-script works when I call using my owned g-Ads api.

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Seems to me like you're missing the `login-customer-id` parameter or don't set it to the correct value. Would be easier to diagnose if you shared some code.